# Is it possible to change the camera view in the FIFA 12 practice arena?

Tags: fifa-12

In FIFA 12 (and some previous versions of FIFA) when you first start up the game you can control a player and practice playing against an AI goalie on an otherwise empty warm-up field. This also occurs before each match.

My problem with it is that the camera view is always facing the goal, whereas the usual camera view for matches in FIFA is the side-on view from high on the sideline. This means that practising shooting is a little pointless as you will never see the goal like that in a proper match.

Is there any way to change the camera view in the practice arena?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havent played FIFA for a while so this isn't 100% but I'm pretty sure there is no way to change the camera. All u can do is check the different camera settings in the option menu, and if it isn't there then sadly no there is no way to change it. The warm up is mainly for fun and not for real match practice.